# Scripts to E-mail Myself a File

Tags: command-line, email

The following command e-mails myself a file:

`sudo mail -a FILE_ADDRESS -s "Subject of E-mail" myemail@gmail.com`

Question: How do I turn this command into a one-liner, so that I could just type something like

`email_myself FILE_ADDRESS`

A related question is as follows: is there a way for me to make it so that all I have to do is just right-click on a file, and then I can execute this command on it?  Or do something like e-mail myself the contents of my clipboard (such that if it's a file, it e-mails me the file, or if it's text, it e-mails me the text)? (Note I'm using Ubuntu).
I think this would be an incredibly useful script :)

Answer (score 4):

Make a function:

```
email_myself() { sudo mail -a "$1" -s "Subject of E-mail" myemail@gmail.com; }
```

If you want your function to hang around permanently, and assuming that `bash` is your shell, add the definition as a line to your `~/.bashrc`.

For those who prefer shell scripts to functions, create a file named `email_myself`, make it executable (`chmod +x email_myself`), and save it somewhere on your `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mail -a "$1" -s "Subject of E-mail" myemail@gmail.com
```

#### Other `mail` programs

On my system, the `mail` command does not work like that.  For one, `sudo` is unnecessary.  For another, `-a` does not attach a file; it is used to specify additional headers.  Thus, I would use:

```
email_myself() { mail -s "Subject of E-mail" myemail@gmail.com <"$1"; }
```

Comment: I add a bin/ directory to my home directory and place shell scripts and other tools there (adding ~/bin/ to path).  But a shell function works...

Comment: @ChuckCottrill My ~/bin directory has over 500 scripts in it.  I have found, though, that there are many who prefer functions.